# GDB + Core file dump

Tags: gdb

Can some please help me to understand this:-

Below is an extract from gdb. After my program crashed, I opened the binary and core file in gdb and issued the command `info frame`:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xb75f7390:
 eip = 0x804877f in base::func() (testing.cpp:16); saved eip 0x804869a
 called by frame at 0xb75f73b0
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0xb75f7388, args: this=0x0
 Locals at 0xb75f7388, Previous frame's sp is 0xb75f7390
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0xb75f7388, eip at 0xb75f738c
```

What do the lines "ebp", "eip", "Locals at" and "Previous Frame's sp " mean? Please explain

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interpret GDB "info frame" output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144727/how-to-interpret-gdb-info-frame-output)

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144727/how-to-interpret-gdb-info-frame-output. Why do you keep asking the same question?

Comment: He is probably trying to get a more descriptive answer, probably didn't want to put the effort into reading all those wikipedia links.

Answer (score 6):

This diagram from the Wikipedia article [Call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) may help: [image: Stack frame layout]

GDB's `info frame` corresponds to functions being called in your program at run time. From the output, we can infer this about the stack frame layout:

- **0xb75f7388**: The 4 bytes starting here stores the old **EBP** value, **0xb75f73a8**. The first value pushed by the function prologue of `base::func()`
- **0xb75f738c**: The 4 bytes starting here stores the return address, **0x804869a**. Pushed by the `call` instruction in the previous frame
- **0xb75f7390**: The 4 bytes starting here stores the implicit `this` argument to `base::func()`, **0x00000000**.

I'll explain the `info frame` output line by line:

```
Stack level 0, frame at 0xb75f7390:
```

Stack level 0 means this is the *newest* frame. The address after `frame at` is called the Canonical Frame Address (CFA). On x86, this is defined to be the value of the stack pointer (**ESP**) at the previous frame, before the **call** instruction is executed.

```
 eip = 0x804877f in base::func() (testing.cpp:16); saved eip 0x804869a
```

**EIP** is the x86 instruction pointer. `saved eip` is the return address.
If you try to look up the function that contains **0x804869a** with `info symbol 0x804869a`, it should point inside the function calling `base::func()`.

```
 called by frame at 0xb75f73b0
```

`called by` shows the canonical frame address of the previous frame. We can see that the stack pointer advanced 32 bytes (0xb75f73b0 - 0xb75f7390 = 32) between the two frames.

```
 source language c++.

 Arglist at 0xb75f7388, args: this=0x0
 Locals at 0xb75f7388, Previous frame's sp is 0xb75f7390
```

The x86 ABI passes arguments on the stack. `base::func()` only has the single implicit `this` argument. The fact that it's `0x0` i.e. `NULL` bodes ill. On a side note, `Arglist` and `Locals` seem to always have the same value in `info frame` on x86 and x86-64.

```
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0xb75f7388, eip at 0xb75f738c
```

`Saved registers` reflects the registers that were saved at function entry. It lists where the old register values are saved on the stack. Saved **EIP** is the return address so if you examine the address stored at **0xb75f738c** with  `x/a 0xb75f738c` it should give **0x804869a**. The fact that **EBP** is listed here implies that your code probably was not compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer` and has a standard function prologue:

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

at the very begging of `base::func()` which sets up **EBP** to act as the frame pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze core file, execute:

$gdb executable core

gdb$ bt   -- backtrace

or gdb$ fr 0   -- the uppermost frame in the run-time stack
   gdb$ fr 1 & so on will give you the order of function calls which led to Seg Fault.

Here, gdb$info frame is providing you info about frame 0.