# perf_event_open always returns -1

Tags: linux, arm, system-calls, perf

I run the following program which call perf_event_open syscall in:
Linux sama-desktop 3.18.0-20-rpi2 #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Sun Apr 5 01:56:02 UTC 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

The program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1

#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr* event_attr, pid_t pid, int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    return syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, event_attr, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
}

static void perf_event_handler(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void* ucontext) {
    if(info->si_code != POLL_HUP) {
        // Only POLL_HUP should happen.
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ioctl(info->si_fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_REFRESH, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Configure signal handler
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sa.sa_sigaction = perf_event_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    // Setup signal handler
    if (sigaction(SIGIO, &sa, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error setting up signal handler\n");
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Configure perf_event_attr struct
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;     // Count retired hardware instructions
    pe.disabled = 1;        // Event is initially disabled
    pe.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_IP;
    pe.sample_period = 1000;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;  // excluding events that happen in the kernel-space
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;      // excluding events that happen in the hypervisor

    pid_t pid = 0;  // measure the current process/thread
    int cpu = -1;   // measure on any cpu
    int group_fd = -1;
    unsigned long flags = 0;

    int fd = perf_event_open(&pe, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        perror("perf_event_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Setup event handler for overflow signals
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK|O_ASYNC);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETSIG, SIGIO);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);     // Reset event counter to 0
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_REFRESH, 1);   // 

// Start monitoring

    long loopCount = 1000000;
    long c = 0;
    long i = 0;

    // Some sample payload.
    for(i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
        c += 1;
    }

// End monitoring

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);   // Disable event

    long long counter;
    read(fd, &counter, sizeof(long long));  // Read event counter value

    printf("Used %lld instructions\n", counter);

    close(fd);
}
```

which returns Error opening leader. I checked the fd and it looks like that it always returns -1.

I used the second example from the perf syscall manual which have the same problem(Error opening leader triggered by fd=-1). Here is the sample code for the perf in the manual:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <sys/ioctl.h>
   #include <linux/perf_event.h>
   #include <asm/unistd.h>

   static long
   perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                   int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
   {
       int ret;

       ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                      group_fd, flags);
       return ret;
   }

   int
   main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       struct perf_event_attr pe;
       long long count;
       int fd;

       memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
       pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
       pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
       pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
       pe.disabled = 1;
       pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
       pe.exclude_hv = 1;

       fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
       if (fd == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       printf("Measuring instruction count for this printf\n");

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
       read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

       printf("Used %lld instructions\n", count);

       close(fd);
   }
```

I also made my own code to just check if the perf having problem accessing the PMU registers. Therefor, I made a kernel module to enable user mode access to PMU registers.

the kernel mode only execute the following:

```
    asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" :: "r"(1));
    asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" :: "r"(1));
```

and then I tried to run the perf_event_open

```
init(void)
{
        static struct perf_event_attr attr;
        attr.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
//      attr.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
        attr.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
        fddev = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr, 0, -1, -1, 0);
        printf("The fddev value is %d", fddev);
}
```

which returns -1. I also used [this repo](https://github.com/thoughtpolice/enable_arm_pmu) which again the fd returns -1.

I also looked at kallsyms to make sure the syscall for perf_event_open is there.

```
root@sama-desktop:/home/sama# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep "perf_event_open"
800f3178 T SyS_perf_event_open
800f3178 T sys_perf_event_open
```

and here is the output from /boot/config-3.18.0-20-rpi2:

```
# 
# Kernel Performance Events And Counters
#
CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_PERF_USE_VMALLOC is not set
CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS=y
# CONFIG_COMPAT_BRK is not set
CONFIG_SLAB=y
# CONFIG_SLUB is not set
# CONFIG_SLOB is not set
# CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING is not set
CONFIG_PROFILING=y
CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=y
CONFIG_OPROFILE=m
CONFIG_HAVE_OPROFILE=y
CONFIG_KPROBES=y
CONFIG_JUMP_LABEL=y
CONFIG_UPROBES=y
# CONFIG_HAVE_64BIT_ALIGNED_ACCESS is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_EFFICIENT_UNALIGNED_ACCESS=y
CONFIG_ARCH_USE_BUILTIN_BSWAP=y
CONFIG_KRETPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KRETPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_TRACEHOOK=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DMA_ATTRS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DMA_CONTIGUOUS=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_SMP_IDLE_THREAD=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_IDLE_POLL_SETUP=y
CONFIG_HAVE_REGS_AND_STACK_ACCESS_API=y
CONFIG_HAVE_CLK=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DMA_API_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_HAVE_HW_BREAKPOINT=y
CONFIG_HAVE_PERF_REGS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_PERF_USER_STACK_DUMP=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_JUMP_LABEL=y
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_IPC_PARSE_VERSION=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_SECCOMP_FILTER=y
CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER=y
CONFIG_HAVE_CC_STACKPROTECTOR=y
CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR=y
# CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_NONE is not set
CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR=y
# CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_CONTEXT_TRACKING=y
CONFIG_HAVE_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN=y
CONFIG_HAVE_IRQ_TIME_ACCOUNTING=y
CONFIG_HAVE_MOD_ARCH_SPECIFIC=y
CONFIG_MODULES_USE_ELF_REL=y
CONFIG_CLONE_BACKWARDS=y
CONFIG_OLD_SIGSUSPEND3=y
CONFIG_OLD_SIGACTION=y
```

and here is output from dmesg:

```
root@sama-desktop:/boot# dmesg | grep "perf"
[    0.003891] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
```

and here is the output for device tree:

```
root@sama-desktop:# ls -la /sys/bus/event_source/devices
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 jul 18 20:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 jan  1  1970 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 jan  1  1970 breakpoint -> ../../../devices/breakpoint
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 jan  1  1970 software -> ../../../devices/software
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 jan  1  1970 tracepoint -> ../../../devices/tracepoint
```

I really do not know why perf_event_open returns -1.

Comment: Do you have the PMUs described in your devicetree? Do you see something like `hw perfevents: enabled with xxx PMU driver, x counters available` fairly early in dmesg?

Comment: No I dont see that. However I wrote my own driver to enable PMU access from used mode. Also I used this repo's driver (https://github.com/thoughtpolice/enable_arm_pmu) which again enable the PMU for user and then uses perf. I updated the question with dmesg output.

Comment: I had problems with `perf_event_open()` working on my x86_64 desktop - my problem turned out to be that my Linux desktop was running in a virtual machine (VMware).  I'm posting this comment because when I had problems with `perf_event_open()` this question was the closest match to the problem I encountered, and I figure that someone else with a similar issue might end up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the lack of anything relevant in dmesg and sysfs, it should hopefully now be apparent that the PMU isn't being described to the kernel. Thus perf events doesn't know anything about the hardware event you're asking for, so it's little surprise that it fails to open it. What you need to do is make sure the kernel *does* know about the PMU, so that the driver picks it up - said driver should already be built-in via CONFIG_HW_PERF_EVENTS, which is on by default with CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS and doesn't look to be disabled in your config, but it might be worth double-checking.

It looks like [the PMU *is* described in the devicetree in their 3.18 kernel](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.18.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2709.dtsi#L95-L98), so my best guess is that your board might be booting using the legacy boardfile rather than FDT. I don't know much about Raspberry Pi specifics, but judging by [this fairly exhaustive article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md) (I'd say skip directly to section 3.1), it seems relatively straightforward to reconfigure the bootloader to use FDT.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes to this question with a Yocto i.MX6 build, like mine, but unlike the OP *does* have something like this in dmesg:

```
hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
```

Try commenting out these two lines in the example code:

```
pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
pe.exclude_hv = 1;
```

For me, that made the `perf_event_open` call succeed and I was able to collect data.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same problem with you, and now my problem is the permission of the program, you should use higher permission to run it so that everything can be right. 
I use `sudo ./a.out`, and then everything is fine.Maybe this will help.

Comment: If this works, you can allow perf for non-root by setting `perf_event_paranoid` more permissive.  e.g. `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using a Rasp B+ (*ARM1176JZF-S processor, an integer core that implements the ARM11 ARM architecture v6*).

Unless the kernel is enabled [(reference and instructions on this publication)](http://web.eece.maine.edu/%7Evweaver/projects/perf_events/rasp-pi/paradis_ece599.pdf), apparently perf_event_open will work from ARMv7 onwards.