# Permission denied on perf_event_open, is there another way than to use sudo or changing the perf_event_paranoid file?

Tags: c, permissions, perf

The only information I could find about the topic is this link:[perf_event_open always returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442839/perf-event-open-always-returns-1), which propose to configure with CONFIG_HW_PERF_EVENTS from what I understood, but I still get the same problem.

I'm implementing a program inspired by the man page of `perf_event_open`:

```
static long
       perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                       int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
       {
           int ret;

           ret= syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                          group_fd, flags);
           return ret;
       }
struct perf_event_attr pe;

int pid = fork();

if (pid > 0 ) {

memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(pe));
           pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
           pe.size = sizeof(pe);
           pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
           pe.disabled = 0;
           pe.exclude_kernel = 0;
           pe.exclude_hv = 0;   
            
           fd = perf_event_open(&pe, pid, -1, -1, 0);
if (fd == -1) {
               perror(0);
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
}
```

I always get a -1 return for fd and perror indicates that permission is denied.

Of course I can work around the problem using sudo, but is there another way to allow permission to execute perf_event_open?

PS: I don't want to change the perf_event_paranoid file, which makes the program work when set at -1; I assume it will be at 2.

Comment: `pe.exclude_kernel = 0;`  Did you read the `EACCESS` and `EPERM` portion of this link:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#RETURN_VALUE `EACCESS` says, in part, "Some common cases where an unprivileged process may encounter this error: attaching to a process owned by a different user; monitoring all processes on a given CPU (i.e., specifying the pid argument as -1); and not setting `exclude_kernel` when the paranoid setting requires it."  `EPERM`: "Returned ... when an unsupported exclude_hv, exclude_idle, exclude_user, or exclude_kernel setting is specified."

Comment: Since your comment is not a full reply, I can't accept it as the correct answer but this actually solved the issue.

Comment: I was posting that right when you added your edit about the paranoid setting, so I wasn't certain about there being a connection.  I'll post it as an answer.  FWIW, that is one looooong man page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**RETURN VALUE** section of the Linux `perf_event_open()` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#RETURN_VALUE) states in part:

> ```
>    ...
>
>    EACCES Returned when the requested event requires CAP_PERFMON
>           (since Linux 5.8) or CAP_SYS_ADMIN permissions (or a more
>           permissive perf_event paranoid setting).  Some common
>           cases where an unprivileged process may encounter this
>           error: attaching to a process owned by a different user;
>           monitoring all processes on a given CPU (i.e., specifying
>           the pid argument as -1); and not setting exclude_kernel
>           when the paranoid setting requires it.
>
>    ...
>
>    EPERM  Returned on many (but not all) architectures when an
>           unsupported exclude_hv, exclude_idle, exclude_user, or
>           exclude_kernel setting is specified.
>
>           It can also happen, as with EACCES, when the requested
>           event requires CAP_PERFMON (since Linux 5.8) or
>           CAP_SYS_ADMIN permissions (or a more permissive perf_event
>           paranoid setting).  This includes setting a breakpoint on
>           a kernel address, and (since Linux 3.13) setting a kernel
>           function-trace tracepoint.
> ```

From the example code posted, the values `pe.exclude_kernel = 0;` or `pe.exclude_hv = 0;` are likely causing permission issues given your statement about the paranoid setting.