# Count c++ instructions executed

Tags: c++, performance, static-analysis

I'm interested in counting the number of c++ instructions executed in a particular c++ program, in order to compare theoretic efficiency (that I've calculated) with efficiency in practice. Calculating theoretic efficiency I'm counting the number of instructions, that's why I need to count the total c++ instructions that the program has executed.

For example, for this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    c++;
    d++;
}
```

It should show me 4 instructions executed (or 6 if we count the automatic i++ on the for loop).

Is there any way to do it? I have searched related questions but I don't want to count instructions in assembly code, I want the c++ instructions count.

Comment: you can write a "parser" which counts it for you

Comment: The thing is, there's really no such thing as a C++ instruction...

Comment: compile to assembly and then count yourself or write a program to count the lines for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "instruction"? A *statement*? An *expression*?

Comment: What is the sense behind that activity? If you want to see how many resources your program requires ( cpu power, ram, cache  ... ) measure with known tools. Execution speed is not counting instructions. It has to do with cache locality, cache miss, optimizing ( compile time constants, loop unrolling, .... ). So all you get by counting your assembly instructions has nearly nothing to do with execution speed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313510/quick-way-to-count-number-of-instructions-executed-in-a-c-program

Answer (score 3):

C++ don't have "instructions" but statements (and it is unclear why `i++, j++;` -which is a single statement with a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)-  should be counted differently than  `i++; j++;` and both could have the *same* [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) and are likely to generate the *same* code in most compilers....)

<sup>(so your question is unclear, and probably makes no sense)</sup>

And a C++ compiler could [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) your code (using the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)) into the equivalent of

```
c += 2;
d += 2;
```

which has the same *observable* behavior as your code chunk. Then what "statement count" do you want to measure? [Loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) is a very common optimization (that most compilers would do).

At last, on modern CPUs (like those in your laptop), the execution time is not much related to the number of C++ statements (or even of [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) instructions) executed, because of [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) issues, [branch predictors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), [instruction pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining), [superscalar processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor), etc...

Perhaps you want [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) tools. On Linux, if you compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -pg -O` then use [gprof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html) (but look also into [perf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html)), you get something close to what you want.

<sup>(I am not sure your question makes real sense; what makes much more sense is the measured time of some benchmark, that you repeat several times and that you make long enough - at least half a second in practice.)</sup>

Read also about [Worst Case Execution Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_execution_time) (WCET). There are tools related to it.

Remember that [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). It cares about timing for arbitrarily large input sizes, and the notion of limit and of convergence is essential when you speak of *O(n)*.

Don't forget that optimizing compilers are changing your code in some significant way. See CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt talk: [*“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”*](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) (which also give hints on why in practice a decent C++ compiler has to make a lot of optimizations; without them C++ would be practically [useless](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065)).

If you are ready to spend months to get a more or less generic solution to your question, you could design and make some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to add instrumentation code into your program. I really think it is not worth the effort, but you are free to try.

Part of the difficulty of such an hypothetical GCC plugin is to measure *precisely* and *unambiguously* what are the statements in every C++ code - including C++ code using standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) which most genuine C++ code use .... You'll find out that it is not simple.... what would be exactly the dynamic statement count -in your ill-defined sense- of some genuine C++ code using [`<vector>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/vector) like `std::vector<int> v(10); v.push_back(2);` ?? Your measure would probably be specific to some particular implementation (e.g. the GCC one) of the C++ standard library.

<sup>(and that is another reason why your question does not make any sense; notice that on my Linux desktop `#include <vector>` expands to nearly ten thousand lines, but most of the statements there get optimized and removed as [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code))</sup>

If you just want to get measures for one particular program, it is simpler (but still useless) to manually add some global counter increment in each of your [basic blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block). If you adopt a particular but verbose -so hard to follow- C++ coding style where each basic block is *syntactically* a block in braces `{}`, that could be easy, and perhaps might be done automatically (at least if you don't use most of C++ features, like its containers).

But I recommend to use *existing* profiling, [code coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage), [benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) and timing tools (e.g. on Linux `gprof`, `perf`, [gcov(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcov.1.html), [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) etc...; see also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html))

Comment: It should show 4 (or 6) too, considering that optimization. So yes, I want statement count. This is because I have calculated the O, and I want to see where the graphic (tests in practice, with different sizes of problem, n) goes, comparing it with the O function.

Comment: What only makes sense is profiling and benchmarking. What you want does not make any sense in practice, and has no actual interest.

Comment: Remember that `c++` statements don't take the same execution time. I mean 1 statement could translate to a single ASM instruction or hundreds. So even if you could count them is the count even meaningful?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch look like I understand the question better than you.. OP is saying that he needs the number of statements. hope you change your vote.

Comment: I'm trying to explain that OP's question makes no sense. You agree on that nonsense, but did not even try to explain why.

Answer (score -1):

check sloccount for linux.

Also, You can use cloc utility to count lines of code.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net/

Runtime number of lines execution may vary according to input data. You can use the profiling tools to understand coverage or which lines are executed more.

Comment: `sloccount` & `cloc` measure the source code, which is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: What the OP is asking doesn't make any sense in the first place.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch read the question again.... for the example. OP is expecting 4 as a result (6 as a result). So, accordingly, he is expecting a number of statement or lines of code.

Comment: But OP expects something related to some *execution* of his program. Indeed what he is asking for does not make any sense. Your answers deal only with the source code (and is unrelated to execution). In particular, `sloccount` & `cloc` both (rightly) measure [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch so for that, I had suggested profiling tool ( similar to your answer) as well. but profiling will provide the different result for different input data (in general scenario).

Comment: Yes. But I guess OP wants profiling. Of course, his question is really confusing (and most of us agree that it does not make any sense)

Comment: so I had provided both solutions. one is loc and another is profiling.

Comment: But still no explanation and no hints on why the OP's question makes no sense.