# No epb/eip registers in gdb "info frame"

Tags: c, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow

### Context

When issuing the command `info frame` on my machine (with break point on `main`), the output is as follows:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffdbd0:
 rip = 0x4005b1 in main; saved rip = 0x7ffff7a53b05
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffdbc0, args: 
 Locals at 0x7fffffffdbc0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdbd0
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffdbc0, rip at 0x7fffffffdbc8
```

As I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16539242/3398271), `eip` and `ebp` registers (not present in my output), have the following meaning:

> eip is the register for next instruction to execute (also called program counter)
>
> "ebp" is the register usually considered as the starting address of the locals of this stack frame, which use "offset" to address

From [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36529824/3398271), I understand that

> [RIP is] the instruction pointer
>
> [...]
>
> Some of these registers were envisioned to be used for specific use, and commonly are. The most critical ones are the RSP and RBP.

Finally, `info registers` gives me the following output:

```
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x4005ad 4195757
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x0      0
rdx            0x7fffffffdcc0   140737488346304
rsi            0x7fffffffdca8   140737488346280
rdi            0x2      2
rbp            0x7fffffffdbc0   0x7fffffffdbc0
rsp            0x7fffffffdbc0   0x7fffffffdbc0
r8             0x7ffff7dd7c60   140737351875680
r9             0x7ffff7dead10   140737351953680
r10            0x7fffffffda50   140737488345680
r11            0x7ffff7a53a10   140737348188688
r12            0x4004b0 4195504
r13            0x7fffffffdca0   140737488346272
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x4005b1 0x4005b1 <main+4>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

(N.B.: tried with `info all-registers` as well. Much longer output, still no eip/epb -- which I was expecting, since according to documentation, these are vector/FPU registers.)

Based on all this, I suppose that:

- on my machine there are no epb/eip registers
- instead of eip, rip is always used on my machine
- instead of ebp, rbp is always used on my machine

### Questions

1. Is the above understanding correct?
   (**Theory B**: there **are** these registers on my machine as well, but gcc compiled the program in such a way, that it uses rip instead of eip and rbp instead of ebp. **Theory C**: since I broke at the beginning of a function, not inside it, eip and ebp are not yet used; rip and rbp serve some other purpose in this case.)
2. (Assuming my main theory is correct): is it the case that newer machines have eip/ebp instead of rbp/rip, or do newer machines have both sets of registers, and older ones only rbp/rip?
3. If `info registers` in gdb does not show a register, does that mean that that register does not exist on the machine, or that it might exist, but is not used in the context of the debugged program? (Based on [GDB documentation](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/info_registers), I would suppose the former.)

### Background

I am trying to do [this exercise](https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/stack4/), whose main point is:

> Stack4 takes a look at overwriting saved EIP and standard buffer
> overflows.

So the main question would be: **should I go for rip instead of eip in this case**? (However, besides answering this point, I would like to have a better understanding of the background in general, therefore the above, more detailed questions.)

Comment: try `print $ebp` and `print $pc` you'll get registers unlisted but working. But it doesn't work for `eip`

Comment: EBP is the low half of RBP.  `-fomit-frame-pointer` is the default, so don't expect to see stack-frame stuff.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for some what's-new-in-x86-64 links, and register diagrams showing what's a subset of what.  Or [build 32-bit executables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649), so you can follow the 32-bit tutorial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exercise was written, I imagine, for the i386 architecture, which is the older 32-bit x86 variant.  The `%ebp`, `%eip` registers are the 32-bit versions of these registers.

You are running, I imagine, on x86-64, the 64-bit x86 variant.  For this version of the architecture these registers are extended to 64-bits, and have new names `%rbp` and `%rip`.

When compiling on x86-64 it's often possible to compile code for the 32-bit x86 ABI, if you're using `gcc` then add the `-m32` flag at compile time.  If you do this then GDB will show you the `%ebp` and `%eip` registers.

In general you should consider `%rip` as just a 64-bit version of `%eip`, and `%rbp` as a 64-bit version of `%ebp`.

Comment: No imagination needed.  Seeing `rip = 0x4005b1` in the output is absolute confirmation that this is x86-64.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Andrew. Although not directly stated, I can infer the answers to my original questions from your answer. (1. Kind of correct: while the registers do not exist with this name, 64-bit versions with the same name exist. 2. Not correct, it is the other way round :) 3. Kind of correct, but it is possible to "emulate" the 32 bit versions of the registers, by using `-m32` flag)