# Meaning of GDB “info frame” output?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, frame

What is the difference between the two Instruction pointers (eip)? What is the goal of each one?

Frame info image:

[image: See frame image here]

There are two different eip?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144727/how-to-interpret-gdb-info-frame-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`saved eip` is the address that your frame will *return* to (i.e. on `i*86` it's the address of the next instruction after the `CALL`).

`eip` is the *current* instruction pointer, i.e. the address of instruction that is going to be executed next (once control returns to this frame).

Comment: and the first eip (on the left)?

Comment: @Marcus Updated.

Comment: What about the one at the bottom?

Comment: @aaaakshat If you have a question, you should _ask_ it as a question. The bottom "Saved registers" tells you where in memory the registers are saved. In other words, the value stored at address `0xbffffa90` should be `0x40037f5c`.